# Securing SQL Server for the internet

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005

I hope this question is not too broad.  I am still doing research, but I was hoping to get opinions from some experts.  We are a software provider and our flagship software is accessed through a portal - our SQL servers (active-active-passive cluster) are safely nestled behind our firewalls and only accessed via our application.  We have a very large client looking to do an offshoot and wants direct read-only access to their database.  This is something we have not done before and makes us nervous.  I am hoping for some guidelines to securing SQL server for the internet.

I should say that our cluster contains hundreds of client databases, only one of which will be accessed through this internet connection.  We are open to adding additional hardware or software layers if necessary. This is SQL 2005.

Thanks all.

Comment: I would try to avoid giving them direct read access. What are their reasons for needing such access? Consider providing an API that will provide them with equivalent access to the data while still providing some level of abstraction between the client and the database.

Comment: We are looking at this option. My security guys are VERY leery of giving access direct to the server from the Internet. We are also looking at options for replication to a new sql instance and getting this new instance access to the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to get a VPN established between your site and their's.  That way you can hook them up to your local network.

The VPN you use should be capable of allowing you to expose access only to the database server itself.

Once you have that, then make sure you setup a specific database user that only has rights to the actual database they need.

Answer (score 2):

If VPN is not an option most firewalls will allow you to setup a policy to a specific inbound ip on a specific port where the remote client static ip has to be in the ip exception list. this way the remote client would only have access to that specific SQL instance. You would then need to create a SQL user only under the "public" server role. then you would need to go user mapping and give that user access to their database only and give them "db_denydatawriter" and "db_datareader" you would probably also want to take away access from listing other databases so that they don't know who your clients are if you use descriptive names for your clients databases.  that can be done under securables under securables. you would have to click search and select "this server" The "permision" us called "view any database". of course you would need SQL authentication for this to work. keep in mind that a client that is not experienced in SQL performance could lock tables, indexes, etc... with poor queries. a list of sprocs written by your shop might be the way to go.

here is an example to get you started.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [remoteuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[CLIENTDB], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [CLIENTDB]
GO
CREATE USER [remoteuser] FOR LOGIN [remoteuser]
GO
USE [CLIENTDB]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'remoteuser'
GO
USE [CLIENTDB]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_denydatawriter', N'remoteuser'
GO
use [master]
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [remoteuser]
GO
```

Comment: My security guys are VERY nervous about allowing a shared sql server to be accessed from the Internet, even if limited by IP. Other than that, everything you say is agreeable.

Comment: yeah, this should always be a last resort. i think your idea of replication on another server would be a better alternative, but i would still lock down the new instance the same. Provided my answer because i know sometimes the right way is not an option.